# preg_match - regex - differentiate between a named subpattern and a pattern starting with same string

Tags: php, regex, routes, preg-match

I am in the process of creating my own url router class for a lightweight MVC framework. I was implementing a simple array based system, and figuring out what the parameters where through a series of loops, etc. I have gone through the django book, and like their system of just matching a pattern, and calling a class and method if the pattern is matched. I have it working well, but am stuck on mapping two different patterns and admittedly I am not the best at regex.

so I have an array of url patterns and corresponding classes/methods:

```
'/^\/users\/(?P<username>\w+)$/' => array('class' => 'userController', 'method' => 'detailUserAction'),

'/^\/users\/update$/' => array('class' => 'userController', 'method' => 'updateUserAction'),
```

and the first pattern is always matched before anything else that starts with /users and has something else after it.

Later on in the code I am looping through the array and executing this code:

```
if (preg_match($urlPattern, $pathString, $matches)){
                $this->invokeObject($command, $matches);
                exit;
            }
```

Any ideas on what pattern I can use to differentiate these two urls?

one is /users/username

and the other is /users/update

I guess I can always just include the other ones first in the order in the array, is that my best option?

Comment: yes, put your specific routers first (like /users/update) and put your catch all routers at the end (like /users/username)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the URI design should be refined in this case. What if a user is called "update", "add", or "delete"?  It will add special cases in your username pattern and not easy to maintain/expand in the future.

But if the  means the user id, I  think you can change the subpattern to (?P\d+) which can make remove the ambiguity.

Comment: gave some thought to this, I am wondering what other frameworks would do to prevent this from happening when defining the url patterns?  I am thinking for my homegrown approach, I can check my url routing config array to see if anything would conflict when I am registering users or something that would conflict with any reserved words in the url like update.